# Apple Script: How to set the alignment of content to Right to Left in New mail scree

Tags: applescript

I have an apple script that opens the compose mail(new mail) screen.I have to support Arabic language and alignment for Arabic should be right to left. Can anyone tell me how to achieve it. Default alignment is Left to Right.

I am using the below code but its not working.

```
set paragraph direction of newMessage to right to left direction
```

While Compiling this code, I get the error:

```
Syntax Error: A to:left can’t go after this right
```

Comment: I don't see `paragraph direction` anywhere in the Mail Dictionary. Where did you find that code?

Comment: I also didn't find it in the Mail Dictionary. I was searching it on internet and found somewhere so I thought it may work. I am not sure whether its possible to align the content of mail to right to left. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: @akhilshrivastav Manually, you can choose Format/Alignment/Writing Direcetion. Perhaps you can do the same with GUI scripting.